# Ajax call to Php script to fetch image in base64 string working on localhost but not from hosting server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess

*Description:* I have a HTML page which onloading triggers Ajax call. In this Ajax call I'm passing in the ids(which is the same as image name which are placed on server) .Each id sent via ajax function to the php script which then fetches the image convert it to base64 and returns it back to ajax call. On success this Javascript function writes base64 string to(href="base64") the corresponding id it came from.

*Problem:* Now all of this is working fine on localhost with directives in .htaccess file but just when I placed it on my hosting server the HTML page is making the ajax call to PHP script but the PHP script is not returning the base64 string as on localhost but is returning the markups of Index.html. In my .htaccess file on server I have condition that "# Redirect all requests to index.html" (but that's only to avoid any unwanted requests from user).

*Checks performed:* 1) case sensitivity of names.
2)Have placed the files in correct directory locations.
3)Compared the requests(using Developers tool,Network tab) that's made on localhost with the one on hosting server and both are same with 'Status 200' (their content 'base64string' and 'markups of index.html' respectively).

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="example-image-link" id="travel_1"></a>
<a href="#" class="example-image-link" id="travel_2"></a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.example-image-link').each(function() {

var id = $(this).attr("id");
var data = id;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'http://mysite.in/home/myname/public_html/image_extract.php',
async: true,
data: {post: data},
success: function(data) {
var x = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
var y = data;
 z = x + y;  

document.getElementById(id).href= z; 
    return false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

**image_extract.php**

```
$q = $_POST['post'];
$main = explode("_", $q);

if($main[0] == "travel")
{
$dir = "images/travel_pics/".$q.".jpg";
$image = file_get_contents($dir);
$imdata = base64_encode($image);
    if ($imdata !== false) {
        echo $imdata;
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
}
```

**.HTACCESS**

```
# Allows ModRewrite to work
Options FollowSymLinks

# Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect all requests to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html

IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite.in/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite.in$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mysite.in/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mysite.in$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

Why am I not receiving base64 string from php script on hosting server(Godd*dy)? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you changed ajax `url` parameter after moving to remote server?

Comment: @Justinas yes I did. I am getting response from the php script just the response contents are different (when on localhost- base64 string which I wanted and when on remote server- markups of Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess looks fine, JS also - it seems like the php file image_extract does not exist.

You are using path **http://mysite.in/home/myname/public_html/image_extract.php**

try **http://mysite.in/image_extract.php** instead because /home/myname/public_html is your document root (i suppose).

Comment: I tried that too but still can't get it to work. Though initially I could access the php file it's just that it is not returning base64 string instead it returns me the markup of Index.html. still Thanks for your suggestion